# Mongo how can I do conditional update with $addToSet?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to update only documents which not contains dynamic counters with $addToSet and bulk write.

I wrote such code (upsert of game position and next move - one position can have multi move:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.drop_database('delete_it')
db = client.delete_it


def first_position(position):
    db.position.update_one(
        filter={
            'position': position
        },
        update={
            '$setOnInsert': {
                'position': position
            },
            '$inc': {
                'counts': 1,
            }
        },
        upsert=True
    )


def next_position(position, move, previous_position):
    db.position.update_one(
        filter={
            'position': previous_position,
        },
        update={
            '$addToSet': {
                'next_positions': {
                    'position': position,
                    'move': move,
                }
            },
        }
    )
    db.position.update_one(
        filter={
            'position': previous_position,
            'next_positions.position': position
        },
        update={
            '$inc': {
                'next_positions.$.counts': 1
            },
        }
    )


# first

position = 0

first_position(position=position)

# second

previous_position = 0
move = 1
position = 1

next_position(position=position, move=move, previous_position=previous_position)

previous_position = 0
move = 1
position = 1

next_position(position=position, move=move, previous_position=previous_position)
```

All works but generates duplicated counters. Can I make some condition for update to not allow duplicates with `$addToSet`. I want add `position` and `move` pair (ignoring value of counter) if counter is not already created?

This code generates duplicates:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb2c732407e06da40d56638"},"position":{"$numberInt":"0"},"counts":{"$numberInt":"1"},"next_positions":[

   {"position":{"$numberInt":"1"},"move":{"$numberInt":"1"},"counts":{"$numberInt":"2"}},
   {"position":{"$numberInt":"1"},"move":{"$numberInt":"1"}}

]}
```

It should just update counters (one entry):

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb2c732407e06da40d56638"},"position":{"$numberInt":"0"},"counts":{"$numberInt":"1"},"next_positions":[

   {"position":{"$numberInt":"1"},"move":{"$numberInt":"1"},"counts":{"$numberInt":"2"}},

]}
```

Maybe should be some conditional `$addToSet`. I want use it in bulk mode but no problem if you suggest solution not using bulk mode. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I am having a hard time following the question. Consider adding the schema to it?

Comment: I write often dynamic code so for me it is not problem no schema. In MongoDb my experience is low so writing schema is very hard for me. I found some solutions for problem but not sure if it effective - need to learn speed of MongoDb.

Comment: I meant describe your data model in your question.